# Advance to same level

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs, synonyms

I was trying to think of a verb today that means "to advance multiple developmental paths to the same level."  An example of a context in which this would be useful is in data storage.  I have two harddrives with much of the same information, but both have been modified separately.  I want to "merge" their paths in Git terms.  However, does anyone know a more general term for this?

Comment: For some aspects of your description, 'graduate' seems appropriate (emphasis on the unified standard acheived - 'same level'); for others 'unify', 'homogenize','acheive','set','converge','standardize','reintegrate','link' (more descriptive of aspects of the process you're describing) - any of these useful?

Comment: _synchronize_, perhaps?

Comment: What do you mean by "development paths"? And what do you mean by "to the same level"? You cannot assume we inderstand "git" terms.  If a document, program, or data file at one time had a single instance, and now has two (or more) distinct versions, I would say they had "diverged" and are in need of being "reconciled".

Comment: Wow, I don't know why I didn't think of synchronize.  Converge and unify also apply, but I associate unify more with opinions.  I thought of integrate, but that would be more appropriate if I was taking the changes from one and only bringing it into a "main" path.  I really like homogenize and reconcile too @bruised reed and Brian Hitchcock; good when I want to be more poetic. I would give you guys votes, but can't at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the term you are looking for is 'synchronize'. You want to bring both independent states together to match each other. Another example is synchronized swimming, where each swimmer copies the movements of the others. Another example is to synchronize calendars, so one calendar matches another calendar, or synchronize schedules.